# Comparing regression models in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I need to test if figures from the 1999-2001 period significantly improved since 2002-2004 period. I tried pooling the data into these two periods and comparing adjusted R-squares of a linear regression model (e.g., lm(Y~A+B)) but that does not lead to the right conclusion. I suppose a by-company regression would be more relevant because regression coefficients will naturally differ from company to company.

How can I do such a by-firm regression in R? Or is there another way of testing if my model has become a 'better fit' over the two periods? Thanks

Data looks something like this (way more companies of course):

```
Company Year    Y           A             B
11308   1999    -0,0208100  0,014718891 -0,006672241 
11308   2000    -0,0073200  0,01513105  -0,001765405 
11308   2001    -0,0242500  0,026331427 0,011924914 
11308   2002    0,0071770   0,033910057 -2,55861E-05 
11308   2003    -0,0161000  0,039996572 0,003413556 
11308   2004    -0,0283000  0,038958565 0,004018833 
11850   1999    -0,0001400  0,044492288 0,008268478 
11850   2000    -0,0023400  0,057337917 0,028973756 
11850   2001    -0,0113100  0,049981605 -0,002928416 
11850   2002    0,0055080   0,04095854  -0,015228795 
11850   2003    -0,0150000  0,089150637 0,042316779 
11850   2004    0,0065680   0,093468014 0,016125354
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an r-to-z transformation might work quite well here: http://vassarstats.net/rdiff.html

This package in R can do it for you: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cocor/cocor.pdf